# WPF JpegEncoder/Decoder preserve DPI precision during disk read/write

Tags: wpf, bitmap, dpi

I am encountering an issue when reading and writing a BitmapSource to disk using a JpegEncoder/Decoder. The following code sample illustrates the problem:

```
        //initialize with some dummy test data
        int outputHeight = 100;
        int outputWidth = 100;
        int outputStride = 100 * 3; //24 bpp            
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[100 * outputStride];

        double dpiX = 20.5;
        double dpiY = 20.5;

        //generate image
        BitmapSource testOutput = BitmapImage.Create(outputWidth, outputHeight,
            dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null,
            outputBytes, outputStride);

        Trace.Assert(testOutput.DpiX == dpiX); //succeeds
        Trace.Assert(testOutput.DpiY == dpiY); //succeeds

        //write to disk
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"F:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\test.jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(testOutput));
            encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
            Trace.Assert(encoder.Frames[0].DpiX == dpiX); //succeeds
            Trace.Assert(encoder.Frames[0].DpiY == dpiY); //succeeds
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }

        //read back
        using (Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(@"F:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\test.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource reread = decoder.Frames[0];

            Trace.Assert(reread.DpiX == dpiX); //fails; reread.DpiX is 21.0
            Trace.Assert(reread.DpiY == dpiY); //fails; reread.DpiY is 21.0
        }
```

As indicated in the comments, the DPI that is read back is not equal to the input value. It seems that either during the encoding or decoding process, the DPI attributes are being rounded to the nearest pixel.

Is there a way to retain the number to the right of the decimal point in the DPI attributes of the image that is read back from disk?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the API allows you to pass in a double (and hence a value like 20.5), DPI values are integers. Therefore the API is rounding (up in your case) to the nearest integer. Do you expect any difference between a DPI of 20.5 and 21.0?

Comment: Hmm, do you have a reference? At least in the BitmapImage class, DPI values with fractional components are handled as doubles and not rounded (I've added some Assert statements to hilight this).

The fractional component of the DPI is important to me because it affects the ActualHeight and ActualWidth of a BitmapSource. With high-resolution images, the difference between 20.5 and 21.0 DPI has a noticeable effect on these properties.

Comment: I thought I read it on Wikipedia, but upon reading it again I think I mis-interpreted it.

Comment: Doesn't your example's failed assert demonstrate that it has been rounded? I am no DPI expert, but is there a way to check the DPI setting of the saved file to see if the change happens on the way out or in?

Comment: If I inspect properties of the output image (F:\Users\Caleb\Desktop\test.jpg) in Windows Explorer, the DPI that's reported is the rounded value, which leads me to believe that the DPI is rounded before writing to disk.

Comment: So if you set them to 20.3, will they be saved as 20.0?

Comment: What is the value of encoder.Frames[0].DpiX just before you call Save()?

Comment: Also BitmapFrame.Create() has some overloads that give you more options (one of them includes DpiX).

Comment: Correct. Interestingly, the first two tests also fail with the 20.3 value. testOutput.DpiX apparently has the value 20.299999237060547 instead of 20.3

Comment: The BitmapFrame.Create() overload that includes DpiX creates a BitmapSource instead of a BitmapFrame, which can't be added to the Frames array. I added some Assert statements to demonstrate the value of encoder.Frames[0].DpiX is the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure what's going on with the JpegBitmapEncoder/Decoder chain, but using the BmpBitmapEncoder/Decoder instead yields results that are accurate to the nearest 10th of a pixel. Not ideal, but it will probably work for the my application.